# Intercepting action methods of an MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I use an O/R mapper, that can reload objects from the DB in a generic manner. I would like to be able to intercept the request *right after* the creation of the mapped objects, in order to reload them.

ActionFilters are of course there, yet the problem is that ActionFilters (or the examples I have seen) can handle the data as provided by the form and not after an object had been created.

I looked at the overridable methods of the Controller, but found nothing obvious that caught my eyes. Does any one know of a way to do this?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Nasser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a custom model binder.  You can inherit from the default ModelBinder class and provide the logic you want.

For example, if you have this:

```
public ActionResult Save([Bind(typeof(CustomModelBinder))] Customer customer)
{
   /* ... */
}
```

The model binder will create the object for you, but you can choose to fetch it from the database first (for existing records).

Comment: Dear Ben!
Thank you for your reply!  I found the code to the modelbinder that comes with the O/R Mapper I use, so I now must try and work out the reload within the modelbinder!

Thank you for your reply!

Nasser

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand you need something like this.

```
public class Navigate : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        ViewResult view = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;

    }
}
```

In view you will find view.ViewData.Model that belongs to current Controller and you can do all that you want with this mapped data.
Let me know if I was right :)

Comment: Dear Omoto!
thank you for your reply.

You answer deals with the result AFTER the action.  I am actually interested in getting at the mapped objects prior to the action being hit. 

Greetings

Nasser